# Make a new login after the first failure in a React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

## Goal:

If you have failed to login, a message below the button should dispaly about failing login, please try again.  Then the button should be able to be active again without the loading spining icon.   In other words, a new chance to make a new login.

## Problem:

When you tried logging in and then it failed. It always spinning. I do not know how to make a new login try that the end user can log in again.

## My attempt:

Here are is a working example on  [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-sz7nee?file=style.css) and the essential of my code below.

App.tsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Navigate,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';
import { handle_loginnn } from './handle_login';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Authentication state - ', isAuthenticated);
  }, [isAuthenticated]);

  const handle_login = async (username: string, password: string) => {
    // must use async for token
    let ddddd = await handle_loginnn(username, password);

    if (ddddd.length > 0) {
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
    } else {
      alert('Login failed');
    }
  };

  const handle_logout = () => {
    setIsAuthenticated(false);
  };

  const authenticatedRoutes = (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home handle_logout={handle_logout} />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
      </Routes>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  const nonAuthenticatedRoutes = (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login handle_login={handle_login} />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/login" />} />
      </Routes>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  return (
    <Router>
      {/* <IonRouterOutlet> */}

      {isAuthenticated ? authenticatedRoutes : nonAuthenticatedRoutes}

      {/* </IonRouterOutlet> */}
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

---

handle_login.tsx:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const handle_loginnn = async (username: string, password: string) => {
  const login = {
    username: username,
    password: password,
  };

  try {
    // must use async for token
    const response = await axios.post('', login);

    return response.data.token;
  } catch (e) {
    let result = (e as Error).message;

    console.log(result);

    return '';
  }
};
```

---

Login.tsx:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import './style.css';

interface LoginProps {
  handle_login: () => void;
}

const Login: React.FC<LoginProps> = (props) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const inputUsername = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const inputPassword = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

  function handle_login() {
    //let username = "userAlpha";
    //let password = "123";

    let username = inputUsername.current?.value!;
    let password = inputPassword.current?.value!;

    setTimeout(() => {
      props.handle_login(username, password);
    }, 1000);

    setLoading(true);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <title> Login </title>
      <div className="container">
        <strong>login page</strong> <br />
        <br />
        <input type="text" ref={inputUsername} />
        <br />
        <input type="password" ref={inputPassword} />
        <br />
        <button onClick={handle_login} disabled={loading}>
          {loading && (
            <span style={{ marginRight: '5px' }}>
              <span className="lds-ring">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
              </span>
            </span>
          )}
          <span>Login</span>
        </button>{' '}
        <br />
        <div id="asdf"></div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ikftss), and what I did to make it work:

- In `App.tsx`, change `handle_login`, so it returns a boolean, `true` if the login succeed and `false` otherwise, like so:

```
const handle_login = async (username: string, password: string) => {
    // must use async for token
    let ddddd = await handle_loginnn(username, password);

    if (ddddd.length > 0) {
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

- In `Login.tsx`, first define a state to handle the error message:

```
 const [error, setError] = useState('');
```

- In `Login.tsx` again, change `handle_login`, so you could use the boolean you get from `App.tsx`:

```
 function handle_login() {
    //let username = "userAlpha";
    //let password = "123";

    let username = inputUsername.current?.value!;
    let password = inputPassword.current?.value!;
    setError('');
    setTimeout(async () => {
      const result = await props.handle_login(username, password);
      if (!result) {
        setError('Login failed');
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }, 1000);

    setLoading(true);
  }
```

- Finally show the message error in `Login.tsx` below that button or wherever you want:

```
{error && <p>{error}</p>}
```

Comment: Hello, just wanna let you know that I get this error.

"ERROR in src/Login.tsx:23:12
TS1345: An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness.
    21 |     setTimeout(async () => {
    22 |       const result = await props.handle_login(username, password);
  > 23 |       if (!result) {
       |            ^^^^^^
    24 |         setError('Login failed');
    25 |         setLoading(false);
    26 |       }
"

Comment: @What'sUP make sure you didn't forget to type anything. Because as you can see it's working fine in my [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ikftss).

Comment: The foundation of the sourcecode was created in VS code and then I copied the code to stackblitz.

I tried your code and applied it in VS code and I still get the same error.

I have used all of your code.

Comment: Basd on my experience, It has happened that the code works in stackblitz but it doesn't work in VS code. I just don't know why.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-nzfajt

I needed to make some changes of the code from " handle_login: (username: string, password: string) => void" to "interface LoginProps {  handle_login: (username: string, password: string) => any; }"

The code works in VS code.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I didn't look at that part. Thanks for letting me know. You could use this type if you wanna be more specific `interface LoginProps { handle_login: (username: string, password: string) => Promise<boolean>;}`. I updated my  StackBlitz as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my project. You can see how I solved https://react-ts-jw4tzk.stackblitz.io.

- In Login.tsx, i have passed setLoading function as props in handle_login

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import './style.css';

interface LoginProps {
  handle_login: () => void;
}

const Login: React.FC<LoginProps> = (props) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const inputUsername = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const inputPassword = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

  function handle_login() {
    //let username = "userAlpha";
    //let password = "123";

    let username = inputUsername.current?.value!;
    let password = inputPassword.current?.value!;

    setTimeout(() => {
      props.handle_login(username, password,setLoading);
    }, 1000);

    setLoading(true);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <title> Login </title>
      <div className="container">
        <strong>login page</strong> <br />
        <br />
        <input type="text" ref={inputUsername} />
        <br />
        <input type="password" ref={inputPassword} />
        <br />
        <button onClick={handle_login} disabled={loading}>
          {loading && (
            <span style={{ marginRight: '5px' }}>
              <span className="lds-ring">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
              </span>
            </span>
          )}
          <span>Login</span>
        </button>{' '}
        <br />
        <div id="asdf"></div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

- in handle_login.tsx i passed setLading function to login

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const handle_loginnn = async (
  username: string,
  password: string,
  setLoading: Function
) => {
  const login = {
    username: username,
    password: password,
    setLoading: setLoading,
  };

  try {
    // must use async for token
    const response = await axios.post('', login);

    return response.data.token;
  } catch (e) {
    let result = (e as Error).message;

    console.log(result);

    return '';
  }
};
```

- in Home.tsx i have used setLoading function as props to set false if login credentials are false
- so spinning will stop

```
import React from 'react';

interface HomeProps {
  handle_logout: () => void;
}

const Home: React.FC<HomeProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <header>
        {/* <h2>Home </h2> */}

        <button slot="end" onClick={props.handle_logout}>
          {' '}
          Logout{' '}
        </button>
      </header>
      <title> Home </title>
      <div className="container">
        <strong>Home page</strong>
        <p>Click logout on the titlebar to logout </p>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Hello, can you provide the code via Stackblitz (not this link https://react-ts-jw4tzk.stackblitz.io.)?

Comment: I tried your code in VS code and I get this error "setTimeout(() => {
  > 20 |       props.handle_login(username, password,setLoading);
       |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    21 |     }, 1000);"

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jw4tzk?file=handle_login.tsx
please check out with above link

Comment: @What'sUP yes its not working in VS code.
i think it is not compatible in vs code it was working in stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Just simply create the instance of API endpoint and return it or you can just create POST general API endpoint and sent URL and body from where you call the function.

```
// handle_login.tsx;
import axios from 'axios';

export const handle_loginnn = async (username: string, password: string) => {
  return await axios.post('', { username, password });
};
```

Also create `handle_login` function in `App.tsx` because you are setting `setIsAuthenticated` hook in `App.tsx` well that's not a good approach how to that instead create a global state and do that `isAuthenticated` state, do not need to prop drill `handle_login` function like you do in `route`

```
// App.tsx
const handle_login = async (username: string, password: string) => {
  try {
    await handle_loginnn(username, password);
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};
```

Why are you using useRef in `login.tsx` instead use state for that and set value on onChange event of `input`.

```
// login.tsx
function handle_login() {
  let username = inputUsername.current?.value!;
  let password = inputPassword.current?.value!;

  try {
    await props.handle_login(username, password);
  } catch (error) {
    // show error toast or something to let user know whatever
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    setLoading(true);
  }
}
```